# Jquery iframe transport plugin funciona no IE10 cross domain

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, cors, cross-domain

Necessito postar xml utilizando webservices da Justiça Federal, mas consigo fazer somente usando o IE10 no modo de compatibilidade.
Recebi a informação de que o plugin iframe transport do jquery superaria essa dificuldade.
Isso é real ou devo compatibilizar o meu site e o site da justiça pelo CORS ?

Comment: Não pude encontrar nenhuma documentação sobre como esse serviço funciona. Caso possa dar alguns dados a respeito de como se dá essa transferência (ajax, postmessage, plugins, etc) ficaria mais fácil responder a pergunta.

Comment: A solução mais adequada pra você pegar esses dados e disponibilizar no seu site é trabalhar com uma espécie de tunilamento no seu servidor, onde você comunica o seu servidor diretamente com o servidor hospedeiro e transmite a informação manipulada ao client. Desta maneira não vai infringir CORS e terá compatibilidade com todos os browsers que não apresentam falha de segurança.

Answer (score 1):

Carregar dados via `IFRAME` para driblar CORS quando não se tem possibilidade de um JSONP, é uma solução leviana. Na especificação os browsers devem bloquear esse tipo de recurso permitindo que apenas se o site contendo o Javascript enviar via `postMessage` e interpretar de forma isolada mensagens a ele enviadas.

Se não for este o caso, você estará explorando uma falha de segurança que alguns browsers podem ter, de forma que a tendencia é que essas falhas sejam suprimidas e seu sistema deixe de funcionar. Seja por atualização no browser, plugins de segurança ou anti-virus integrados ao browser do cliente.

Uma solução adequada para dar informações provenientes de outro site ao qual não dispõe estes dados diretamente cliente para cliente, é utilizar um servidor para fazer um tunilamento, como isso funciona:

1. Seu cliente faz uma requisição para o seu servidor
2. Seu servidor modifica a requisição incluindo dados como API_KEY, cookies, etc necessário para comunicar-se com o webservice destino
3. Ele faz o envio e captura a resposta do webservice
4. Trata a resposta e envia de volta ao seu cliente os dados seja raw ou processados

O serviço pode sim ser expandido a um webservice sem problema, desde que seu servidor trate os dados corretamente para enviar ao site que detém as informações desejadas.

Comment: Quando falei plugins imaginei Flash: é possível que o servidor use crossdomain.xml mas não CORS. Tunilamento não causaria nenhum problema legal não? Nunca vi isso (ou similares) com bons olhos.

Comment: Para flash também é limitado o uso de CORS pelos mesmos motivos de segurança dos browsers, se você conseguir, estará explorando uma falha no flash do usuário. Esta solução de usar um servidor para fazer tunilamento não é de forma alguma ilegal, desde que não infrinja as regras do webservice que você está utilizando, como números de requisições, dados cifrados de um usuário, etc. É bom deixar claro na página como os dados do seu usuário serão utilizados e recorrência do uso do webservice ao qual será transposto tais dados.

Comment: O uso do [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/cross-domain-xml-for-streaming.html) não se constitui uma falha, uma vez que foi criado para mesmo propósito do CORS. Quanto ao tunilamento foi bom saber disso.

Comment: É uma falha de segurança quando você "burla" o crossdomain.xml de outro site. Ou o header do mesmo que informa o `allowed-origin` (mais atual).

Comment: Não me referi a burlar o crossdomain mas a um servidor que tem suporte a ele mas não a CORS. O que me levou a essa ideia foi o fato dele estar usando XML.

Answer (score 0):

Este plugin tem alguns problemas de compatibilidade...

http://cmlenz.github.io/jquery-iframe-transport/#section-17

Sugiro traduzir e ler para ver aonde o seu problema possivelmente se encaixa.

Além disto, verifique no seu plugin se o retorno do ajax se dá via callback .success ou .complete, .done, pois a callback .sucess não funciona neste caso.

http://missioncriticallabs.com/blog/2012/04/lessons-learned-from-jquery-file-upload/